# how to convert java multipart file upload program to groovy

Tags: groovy

Below is my code and log of the cast Exception

Getting the castException if i run the same code in groovy IDE (intelli idea)

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class File2 {
    private static String paramNameCobSessionToken = "03172014_0:78bf85ca1f";
    private static String paramNameUserSessionToken = "dvsdfsdff8d7";

    public String verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp(String cobrandSessionToken,String userSessionToken) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String response = null;

        System.out.println("hello");

        String HOST_URI3 = "https://192.168:10443/srest/v1.0/";
        String url = HOST_URI3 + "/updateBridgetData";

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
            PostMethod pm = new PostMethod(url);
            NameValuePair[] params = new NameValuePair[4];
            params[0] = new NameValuePair("cobSessionToken", paramNameCobSessionToken);
            params[1] = new NameValuePair("userSessionToken", paramNameUserSessionToken);
            params[2] = new NameValuePair("bridgetMetaData.bridgetKeyData.bridgetAppId", "10009959");
            params[3] = new NameValuePair("bridgetMetaData.bridgetSource.fileName", "bundle.zip");
            pm.setQueryString(params);

            String sourceFile = "D:\\bundle\\bundle\\bundle.zip";

            File f = new File(sourceFile);
            Part[] parts = {new FilePart("bridgetMetaData.bridgetSource.bundledZipFile", f)};
            pm.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, pm.getParams()));
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

            int RC = hc.executeMethod(pm);
            System.out.println("Response Status Code : " + RC);
            response = pm.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println("The response is " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return response;
    }

    static class NullHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier
    {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        File2 upload=new File2();
        upload.verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp(paramNameCobSessionToken,  paramNameUserSessionToken);
    }
}
```

Error log

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'File2$_verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp_closure1@189f854' with class 
'File2$_verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp_closure1' to class 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part'
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:371)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.asArray(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:445)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:204)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
at File2.verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp(File2.groovy:48)
at File2$verifyAndUpdateBridgetApp.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at File2.main(File2.groovy:75)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[]` not `{}` when defining your `Part[]`

```
Part[] parts = [new FilePart("bridgetMetaData.bridgetSource.bundledZipFile", f)]
```